# App Crash due to FB sdk 3.2

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using new FB IOS SDK and app crash and get below error

> Assertion failure in -FBCacheIndex
>   _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:, /Users/chrisp/src/ios-sdk/src/FBCacheIndex.m Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x334072a3 0x3b0a197f 0x3340715d 0x33cdcb13 0x10b3b1 0x10b635 0x10a7bf 0x3b4b911f 0x3b4b899b 0x3b4b8895
>   0x3b4c7215 0x3b4c73b9 0x3b4eda11 0x3b4ed8a4)

I have made google and found solution like -lsqlite3.0 in other linker flag and add -lsqlite3 framework, FBsession missing. and i have done all but still i am getting same issue.

My code as below:

in FBClass.m which is NSObject type

```
-(void) getFriendListForInvitation
 {

@ try {

    if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];

        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Invite Friends";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
        [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];
        [self.friendPickerController loadData];
        self.friendPickerController.itemPicturesEnabled = TRUE;

    }
    else{
        [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];
        [self.friendPickerController updateView];
    }
    self.friendPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = FALSE;


    // iOS 5.0+ apps should use [UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
    // rather than this deprecated method, but we want our samples to run on iOS 4.x as well.
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5.0)
        [[[appdelegate.navigationController viewControllers] lastObject] presentViewController:self.friendPickerController  animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    else
        [[[appdelegate.navigationController viewControllers] lastObject] presentModalViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[exception description]);
}
```

}

Please help me to solve this issue.....

thanks

Comment: Make your FacebookSDK in build phrases as Optional. not required.

Comment: from the above code which line  crash the app?

Comment: Not crash on my code line... its crash on SDK file on statement FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:

Comment: Is this a FB 3.2 issue only? If so, is there anything stopping you from bumping to use 3.5.1? I recommend adding the Facebook SDK as a Cocoapod it will set all your build flags correctly

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to solve the issue? I suffer from the same problem.
I determined that this exception is caused by the missing file `cache.db` in the directory facebook is addressing to. You can check that with the help of the simulator. The directory of the missing simulator file is:

```
/Users/<user name>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/<app id>/Library/Caches/DataDiskCache
```

Yet I do not know why the file is missing.

EDIT:
The only thing I came up with was to clear the session data from the app with simple two lines of code:

```
FBSession.activeSession = nil;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenInformationKey"];
```

Unfortunately this solution never actually closes the session but at least it is providing the proper workflow of the app.